# I need the a step in this integration clarified. Quadratics.

Tags: integration

I have an integration exam tomorrow and I need to understand how we get$$\Biggl( w+\frac{3}{2}\Biggl)^2$$

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Solutions/CalcII/IntegralsWithQuadratics/Prob1.aspx

I was under the impression that it should be done:

$$w^2+3w+\frac{3}{2}^2+\frac{3}{2}$$

and $$w^2+3x+\frac{3}{2}^2$$should get factored and then get something like:$$(w+a)^2+\frac{3}{2}$$

Its been a long time since I have had to integrate with methods like this. Please clear up any confusion.

Comment: complete the square:  $w^2+3w+3=\left(w^2+3w+\dfrac94\right)+\dfrac34=\left(w+\dfrac32\right)^2+\dfrac34$

Comment: You don't just *add* $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2$, you also have to subtract it. Note that $\frac{3}{2}^2$ looks like $\frac{(3^2)}{2}$, leading to potential confusion...

Comment: I dont understand where the $$\frac{9}{4}$$ came from I mean I get that it came from squaring $\frac{3}{2}$ but how did we get the $3w+\frac{9}{4}$ be equivalent to $\Biggl( w + \frac{3}{2}\Biggl)^2$

Comment: binomial square:  $\left(w+\dfrac32\right)^2=w^2+2 \times w \times \dfrac 32 + \left(\dfrac 32\right)^2=w^2+3w+\dfrac94$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to complete the square on a quadratic trinomial of the form $$ax^2+bx+c,$$ with $a\ne 0,$ first understand that our goal is to attempt to put it in the form $$x^2\pm2xk+k^2$$ since these are $$(x\pm k)^2.$$

Now, how do we make that happen? First factor out the leading coefficient, to get $a(x^2+Ax+B),$ with $A=b/a$ and $B=c/a.$ Then focus on the second factor. The first term is already in the required form. Now the linear term -- we want a $2$ there, so we put it (but we must divide it again, not to change the expression!), and now we have the linear term as $2x(A/2).$ That's the form of the middle term. Finally, we *must* have the last term to be $(A/2)^2.$ So we add it, but we must subtract it back to keep things stable. Doing all these things, we have the expression now as $$[x^2+2xA/2+(A/2)^2]-(A/2)^2+B.$$ The first term in square brackets is now a square, namely $(x+A/2)^2.$ Simplifying the constant terms into one finally gives $$(x+A/2)^2+B-A^2/4.$$ (By the way, you can now immediately tell what must happen for it to be possible to make such expressions perfect squares, but that's only beside the point.)

Can you now apply this to your expression? That is, $w^2+3w+3,$ which begins as $w^2+2w\cdot\frac32+\left(\frac32\right)^2-\left(\frac32\right)^2+3\ldots .$

Answer (score 0):

We want to get the expression $w^2+3w+3$ in the form $(w+a)^2+b=w^2+2aw+a^2+b$.

So take $2a=3$ and $a^2+b=3$.  Can you solve for $a$ and $b$?